# Where are the Dancers?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I am trying to find all the Dancers in Castelia City so I can battle them all and they can form some sort of dance team or something.

I have spoken to and defeated the one by the fountain in the Central Plaza, but other than that, I can't find any Dancers.

Where are they hiding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first dancer is [located by the fountain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=gIRL-M2FgLo#t=410s). The second dancer is [in an alley near a set of dumpsters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=gIRL-M2FgLo#t=479s). The final dancer can be found [at one of the piers at the south area of the city](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=gIRL-M2FgLo#t=541s).